# Setting a column in a dataframe based on a regex condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to set a column in a dataframe to a substring of another column based on a regex condition. One column had a title and, sometimes, a year, such as "Temp (2019)" or just "Temp". I need to extract the year from that title (if it has it) and then remove the year from the original word. So, instead of having one column as "Temp (2019)", I would have two columns, one being "Temp" and the other being "2019". If the title doesn't have a word, put in 0.

```
regex = r"\(\d{4}\)$"
tempYear = df['title'].str[-5:-1]
df['year'] = np.where(re.search(regex, df['title']) != None, df['title'].str[-5:-1], "0")
```

Right now, when I run this, I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
expected string or bytes-like object
  File "[path]", line 63, in <module>
    df['year'] = np.where(re.search(regex, df['title']) != None, df['title'].str[-5:-1], "0")
```

I think it's because I'm using the first condition (if true condition), in that it's a list (I think) instead of a single word. In other words, the if statement has a mix of types. I'm not sure how to extract the year from the title without it though.

The title, if it has a year, will always be in the format "[word] ([year])", with the year being at the end, in parentheses. I can easily do

```
df['year'] = df['title'].str[-5:-1]
```

But this causes issues when there isn't a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas, `str` provides regular expression handling while the standard library `re` module cannot handle pandas series not numpy arrays.

So what you want could more easily be obtained by pandas functions:

```
df['year'] = np.where(df.title.str.contains(regex), df['title'].str[-5:-1], "0")
```